# Update text of label on sort UITable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UITable that sorts the cells alphabetically on common name and on scientific name. Each cell of the UITable has two labels stacked vertically, corresponding to the species' common name and scientific name. I'd like for the text of the labels to change when the user selects a different sort value; ie the top label should be the species common name when they select "common name".

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I set the cell by calling `setSpeciesImage`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"speciesCell";

    SpeciesCell* speciesCell = (SpeciesCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        Species *theSpecies = [speciesFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [speciesCell setSpeciesImage:theSpecies usingImageType:currentImageType sortBy:sortDescriptor];

        speciesCell.checkMark.hidden = YES;
        return speciesCell;
}
```

Inside `setSpeciesImage`, I update the labels text depending on the sort descriptor. However, nothing changes. My labels stay the same.

```
- (void)setSpeciesImage:(Species *)species usingImageType:(NSInteger)imageType sortBy:(NSInteger)sortBy
{
    switch (sortBy) 
    {
        case kSortByCommonNameFirst:
            _primaryLabel.text = [species commonNameFirstLast];
            _secondaryLabel.text = species.scientificName;
            self.isPrimaryLabelItalic = NO;
            self.isSecondaryLabelItalic = YES;
            break;
        case kSortByCommonNameLast:
            _primaryLabel.text = [species commonNameLastFirst];
            _secondaryLabel.text = species.scientificName;
            self.isPrimaryLabelItalic = NO;
            self.isSecondaryLabelItalic = YES;
            break;
        case kSortByScientificName:
            _primaryLabel.text = species.scientificName;
            _secondaryLabel.text = [species commonNameFirstLast];
            self.isPrimaryLabelItalic = YES;
            self.isSecondaryLabelItalic = NO;
            break;
        default:
            _primaryLabel = nil;
            _secondaryLabel = nil;
            self.isPrimaryLabelItalic = NO;
            self.isSecondaryLabelItalic = NO;
            break;
    }

    NSString *imagePath = nil;

    switch (imageType) 
    {
        case kImageTypeLeaf:
            imagePath = [species.ExampleImageLeaf pathForLocalImageUsingThumbnail:YES];
            break;
        case kImageTypeFlower:
            imagePath = [species.ExampleImageFlower pathForLocalImageUsingThumbnail:YES];
            break;
        case kImageTypeFruit:
            imagePath = [species.ExampleImageFruit pathForLocalImageUsingThumbnail:YES];
            break;
        default:
            _speciesImage = nil;
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `segmentedControl` selection action triggers you should call

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I don't sort using a segmented control

Comment: you send **sortBySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex** to sortBy

Comment: besides sorting data logic should be out of cell anywhere then you reload the table with the already sorted data according to the last selection

Comment: Just updated my text so that I pass sortDescriptor, rather than sortBySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex (which was old code, and actually incorrect). Should I call `[self.tableview reloadData]` at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then?

Comment: no , never this will make an infinite loop , i want to know what triggers the sort where the user clicks to sort with different value ???